# Difference between $window.location.reload() and $route.reload() in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, performance

What is the difference between $window.location.reload() and $route.reload() in Angular.js?

I have used these two things, but both are working same progress.

Can anyone explain the differences?

Comment: @Ramesh Rajendran this is your duplicate account ?I am not sure :-P.But it seems to be :-P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$window.location.reload()` - It uses to reload the page

`$route.reload()` - Causes $route service to reload the current route even if `$location` hasn't changed.

As a result of that, ngView creates new scope and reinstantiates the controller.